# Firestore Security Rule to restrict reading chat messages

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

In my 1-1 chat app using Firestore, the 2 participants will read/write docs in `msgs` sub-collection, where each doc is one message.
But it's failing with permission denied, due to the security rules.

The DB structure :

```
chatRooms/
    ${roomId}/
        msgs/
            ${msgId}
```

I want to add security rules so that only the relevant 2 participants will be able to read/write in the `msgs` sub-collection, of their `roomId` doc

I wrote the following security rules.
It let's the participants to create a new doc (i.e. send messages) in `msgs` sub-collection.
But users are not able to read this `msgs` sub-collection.

```
match /chatRooms/{roomId} {
    allow read:   if request.auth.uid == resource.data.userA.id || 
                     request.auth.uid == resource.data.userB.id;
    allow create: if request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.userA.id || 
                     request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.userB.id;

    match /msgs/{msgId} {
        allow read:   if request.auth.uid == resource.data.sender._id ||
                         request.auth.uid == resource.data.partner._id;
        allow create: if request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.sender._id ||
                         request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.partner._id;
    }
}
```

The code for read is :

```
    const roomId = `${userAId}_${userBId}`;
    const query = db.collection('chatRooms').doc(roomId).collection('msgs')
        .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
        .startAfter(lastVisible)
        .limit(10)

    query.get()
```

If I change the read rule like below, the read & write works totally OK.
So we can pin point that the problem is in read rule of the `msgs` sub-collection, only. (And not in its parent collection/doc rules)

```
    match /msgs/{msgId} {
        allow read:   if request.auth != null;
        allow create: if request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.sender._id ||
                         request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.partner._id;
    }
```

---

**UPDATE :**

Frank suggested 3 solutions, and I tried two of them(1 & 3), but both didn't work for me.

For solution 1, I added an `ids` array with participants UIDs.
The write message (adding new doc) worked with same security rule.

[image]

The read op looks like this :

[image]

And this is the security rule :

[image]

---

**UPDATE 2**

It worked after fixing the security rule, as Frank mentioned in comment in his answer. (as this comment is far below, I am adding it here as well)

```
  match /msgs/{msgId} {
    allow read:   if request.auth.uid in resource.data.ids;
    allow create: if request.auth.uid in request.resource.data.ids;
  }
```

---

**UPDATE 3**

The solution 1 required generating an index (as i am using `orderBy` as well) which costs extra. So i tried Frank's solution 3 as well, but it returns permission denied error.
Probably the read query is wrong, and it requires some filter, but I cant add filter on `$roomId` doc data (`userA.id` / `userB.id`) as required by rules, while reading from `msgs` collection.

The Rule :

```
match /chatRooms/{roomId=**} {
  allow read:   if request.auth.uid == resource.data.userA.id || 
                   request.auth.uid == resource.data.userB.id;
  allow create: if request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.userA.id || 
                   request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.userB.id;
  allow update: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.userA.id || 
                   request.auth.uid == resource.data.userB.id;
}
```

The read query :

```
    const query = dbFirestore.collection('chatRooms').doc(roomId).collection('msgs')
        .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
        .limit(10)

    query.onSnapshot( ... )
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Security rules don't filter data. Instead they merely check whether a read operation is allowed.

So if you want to allow the user to only read messages they are part of, you will have to execute a query that selects those messages.

For example: you can select all messages that the user is the sender of with:

```
db.collection('chatRooms').doc(roomId).collection('msgs')
    where('sender._id', '==', firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
```

And now the security rules will check that this query is allowed, and return the corresponding messages.

---

The problem then becomes that you can't perform an OR condition on the `sender._id` and `partner._id` fields. There are a few solutions for that:

1. Store the participant UIDs for each message in an array field (say `participants`), and then use `array-contains` to query:

   ```
   db.collection('chatRooms').doc(roomId).collection('msgs')
    where('participants', 'array-contains', firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
   ```

   And then secure that in the rules with something like:

   ```
   request.auth.uid in resource.data.participants
   ```
2. Model the security for the room on the `/chatRooms/$roomId` level with a lookup on the `msgs` subcollection. This requires two extra gets, but is much simpler aside from that

   ```
   match /msgs/{msgId} {
    allow read: if request.auth != null && 
        (get(/databases/$(database)/documents/chatRooms/$(roomId)).data.userA.id == request.auth.uid
        || get(/databases/$(database)/documents/chatRooms/$(roomId)).data.userB.id == request.auth.uid);
   ```
3. Let the access to `/msgs` be inherited from the room:

   ```
   match /chatRooms/{roomId=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.userA.id || 
                 request.auth.uid == resource.data.userB.id;
   ```

Comment: Thank you @Frank, your explanation is very useful. I think i ll go with the first approach.

Comment: Sorry I wanted to test the solutions first then mark it solved. The 3rd solution didnt work for me, so i tried the first one. But that didn't work either :( --------- The read op:  `query = db.collection('chatRooms').doc(roomId).collection('msgs').where('ids','array-contains',firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)`  ----------- the rule : `match /msgs/{msgId} {
        allow read: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.ids[0] || request.auth.uid == resource.data.ids[1];
    }` -------- although write worked with same rule, and i confirmed `ids` array with participants ids in generated doc

Comment: Please update your question with the new query, rules and a screenshot of a document. It's too hard to read that in comments.

Comment: I have updated the question with the changes i tried ...

Comment: Those array comparisons wont' work, as the query does an `array-contains` while the rules do two `==` checks. I'd expect a `request.auth.uid in resource.data.ids`.

Comment: Although it required an index, but this worked. Thank you very much. You are a saviour.

Comment: Hi @Frank, Since it required an index (which firebase will charge extra), I want to use your third suggestion now. But it didn't work (probably my read req was wrong). What would read query look like in that case ? Do i need to filter on the UIDs in `roomId` doc data ?

Comment: "it didn't work" is a bit vague there. Same as before: edit your question to show what you tried. And please: no screenshots of textual contents this time around.

Comment: Hi @Frank, I've updated the question about my trial with solution 3. Please take a look.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm indeed not sure if this works after all. Mostly: how would the rules validate the read operation from the information you pass in. So it might not be possible with approach 3.

Comment: OK. I understood. Thank you for your support.